# Category's Description field as editor remove <p> tag

Tags: plugins, categories, editor

I have tried both plugin to make Category's Description field as editor with below plugin. but when i update the text it's remove

tag

http://wordpress.org/plugins/rich-tax-description-editor/
http://wordpress.org/plugins/categorytinymce/

tried google also but din't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you outputting the category description? You might need to use something like `apply_filters('the_content', category_description( $category_id ));` or `wpautop(category_description( $category_id ));` to have paragraphs  in the output.

Edit:
Adding what you had in JSFiddle - note where `$term->description` is, I wrap it in `wpautop`. See if that works. If not, try `apply_filters('the_content', $term->description)` instead:

```
<?php                   
            $taxonomies=  array('taxonomy'=>'area-type');
            $terms = get_terms($taxonomies,'orderby=id&hide_empty=0');
            $count = count($terms);
            if ($count > 0) {
                    foreach ($terms as $term) {

                        $id = str_replace("#","",$term->slug);
                        $term_desc .= '<div id="nav_menu_desc_' . $id . 
                        '" class="section hidden formateIt">' . 
                        wpautop($term->description) .'</div>';    
                    }                  
                        echo $term_desc ;   
            }   ?>
```

Comment: Added like this but not working

http://jsfiddle.net/dXGab/

Comment: updated answer above to reflect your code